# Word Problem (Weight)

Tags: word-problem

John made a blanket, which weighed 2.3 kg. He used item A, with the price per kilo of 512 and item B, with the price per kilo of 136. Total price of the items would be 594.80. What is the item A;s, and B;s weight in grams.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? People are more likely to give an answer if they know you have tried and have offered up your ideas.

Comment: I haven't actually tried anything, because this question confused me.

Comment: What have you done on this so far, and where are you having trouble?  You'll find that people will be much more prone to answer your questions if you indicate that you've put some effort into the problem.

Comment: Well the trick is to use simultaneous equations.

Comment: Oh i see i will try that. i was kinda confused what i should use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amount of $A$ we'll call $A$.

Amount of $B$ we'll call $B$.

$A + B = 2.3$ (1)

$512A + 136B = 594.8$ (2)

Subtract $136$ (1) from (2).

$376A = 282$

$A = 0.75$

Substitute in to find $B$.